# how to convert CCSprite to UIImage in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I know that in cocos2d, there's a simple way to convert CCSprite to UIImage by using
[UIImage imageWithData:[renderer getUIImageAsDataFromBuffer:kCCImageFormatPNG]].
However, in cocos2d-x, CCRender do not have such an API as getUIImageAsDataFromBuffer to do the conversion. I wonder is there any possible way to convert a CCSprite to UIImage under cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 1):

CCSprite contains CCTexture2D (accessible with `getTexture()`), try to use it. You can also put texture to `CCImage`, and use `CCImage::saveToFile()`, if there are no better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `UIImage` category I'm using to go from `CCImage` to `UIImage`:

```
#import "UIImage+Conversions.h"

@implementation UIImage (Conversions)

+ (UIImage *) imageFromCCImage:(cocos2d::CCImage *) ccImage {
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                              ccImage->getData(),
                                                              ccImage->getDataLen() * bytesPerPixel,
                                                              NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    NSUInteger scanWidth = ccImage->getWidth() * bytesPerPixel;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(ccImage->getWidth(),
                                        ccImage->getHeight(),
                                        8,
                                        bytesPerPixel * 8,
                                        scanWidth,
                                        colorSpaceRef,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        NO,
                                        renderingIntent);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return image;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method in **UIImageView** called `loadTexture()` which takes a file path and convert the file path into an image and load it to the UIImageView. but this is not the needed approach so we need to implement new method which will take CCNode, i used CCNode here to can add any child of CCNode including the CCSprite

```
void ImageView::addNode(CCNode* node){
    if (!node)
    {
        CCLOG("node is null");
        return;
    }

    CCNode::removeChild(_imageRenderer);
    _imageRenderer = NULL;
    _textureFile = "";
    _imageTexType = UI_TEX_TYPE_PLIST;
    _imageRenderer = node;
    CCNode::addChild(_imageRenderer, IMAGE_RENDERER_Z, -1);
    _imageTextureSize = _imageRenderer->getContentSize();
    imageTextureScaleChangedWithSize();
    updateAnchorPoint();
    updateFlippedY();
    updateRGBAToRenderer(_imageRenderer);
    _imageRenderer->setPosition(getPosition());
}
```

This method removes and nullify the _imageRenderer property which is a CCNode used to add your images on it to be displayed. take in consideration that you need to add the method in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
CCRenderTextureEx* texture = CCRenderTextureEx::create(size.width, size.height);
texture->setPosition(ccp(size.width * 0.5f, size.height * 0.5f));
texture->begin();
sprite->visit();
texture->end();
texture->saveToFile(path->getCString(), kCCImageFormatPNG);
texture->saveImage();
```

And using this custom class:

https://github.com/radif/mcbPlatformSupport/blob/master/mcbPlatformSupport/ios/utils/CCRenderTextureEx.mm

You can generate a CCSprite into an UIImage.